# How To Store the output of INNER JOIN in a table?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am taking two Big Table and extracting data from both table, and now i want to store the extracted output in another table. How can i do this.

Comment: `INSERT INTO .... SELECT ...`?

Answer (score 2):

This is very straightforward:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempname  AS (    
        SELECT whatever, whatever
          FROM rawtable
          JOIN othertable ON this = that
    )
```

The temporary table will vanish when your connection closes. A temp table contains the data that was captured at the time it was created.

You can also create a view, like so.

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS (    
    SELECT whatever, whatever
      FROM rawtable
      JOIN othertable ON this = that
)
```

Comment: How to use your this query with this:

SELECT org_basic.id, org_basic.tmp_org_id, alphanumeric_code.ORG_ID FROM org_basic INNER JOIN alphanumeric_code ON org_basic.id=alphanumeric_code.id ORDER BY alphanumeric_code.id

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempname  AS (    
        SELECT org_basic.id, org_basic.tmp_org_id, alphanumeric_code.ORG_ID 
  FROM org_basic 
  INNER JOIN alphanumeric_code 
  ON org_basic.id=alphanumeric_code.id ORDER BY alphanumeric_code.id 
    )